# Parse MIME sender in Java (RFC 822)

Tags: java, mime, jakarta-mail, rfc822, mime4j

MIME message senders appear in formats such as:

```
"John Doe" <johndoe@gmail.com>
<johndoe@gmail.com>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to extract the string "johndoe@gmail.com" in the above examples, although I will also need the "johndoe" and "gmail.com" parts (per RFC I'm pretty sure splitting on `@` is all that's needed from here).  Obviously regex-ing up my own parser is one (not great) option.

It seemed this may be possible using [`javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html).  All of the constructors require a `Folder` which I do not have (well, I sort of do, it exists in the IMAP layer), e.g.

```
MimeMessage(Folder folder, InputStream is, int msgnum)
```

Which makes me feel I'm using this class wrong. Nonetheless, if I parse this way I do get access to the `getFrom()` method which returns an array of [`Address`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/Address.html), which itself doesn't offer methods of use to me.

Using mime4j it's easy to get this far:

```
case T_FIELD: // field means header
    if(token.getName() == "from") {
        // get raw string as above - unparsed
```

So using mime4j or using java, javax etc. utilities it should be possible to extract the "a@b.com" part of the address from there, but I haven't found a class within javax or mime4j that is responsible for this yet.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need InternetAddress class from javax.mail:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#getAddress()

Minimum working example:

```
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

public class JavaMailExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AddressException {
        String fullemail = "\"John Doe\" <johndoe@gmail.com>";
        InternetAddress addr = new InternetAddress(fullemail);
        System.out.println(addr.getPersonal()); // John Doe
        System.out.println(addr.getAddress());  // johndoe@gmail.com
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, got it from here.  To make this a good answer though you should include how to use it - I upvoted because this helped me but it's close to a link only answer.